# Change some entries of a matrix in maple

Tags: maple

I have a zero matrix in Maple and I need to replace some of its entries with some non zero elements. How do I do that? I also want to find the inverse of the new matrix after replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created the Matrix by using the `Matrix` command then, by default, all its entries are zero. In that case you can subsequently assign to them as you wish, using indexed assignment.

M:=Matrix(2,2):

M;

```
                   [0    0]
                   [      ]
                   [0    0]
```

M[2,2]:=3.7:

M;

```
                   [0     0 ]
                   [        ]
                   [0    3.7]
```

The command to compute the inverse is `LinearAlgebra:-MatrixInverse`. Eg,

M:=Matrix(2,2):

M[2,2]:=3.7:
M[2,1]:=4.1:
M[1,2]:=-0.3:
M[1,1]:=5.9:

M;

```
                     [5.9    -0.3]
                     [           ]
                     [4.1    3.7 ]
```

Minv:=LinearAlgebra:-MatrixInverse(M):

Minv;

```
      [0.160450997398092     0.0130095403295750]
      [                                        ]
      [-0.177797051170859    0.255854293148309 ]
```

M . Minv;

```
                      [1.    0.]
                      [        ]
                      [0.    1.]
```

See the help page for topic `LinearAlgebra` for more.